# Infering set mapping in Matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, combinatorics, decoding

I am trying to infer a mapping scheme from set `A` to `B` (given below). Is there a way (Toolbox, long-forgotten File Exchange Gem, ...) to do that in Matlab?

My `A` and `B` are:

```
A = [8955573624 8727174542 6144057737 6697647320 1335549467 6669202192...
     9276317113 5048034450 4757279524 1423969226 9729294957 4332046813...
     0681780168 8231841017 9809242207 5584677643 6193476760 7203972648...
     7286156579 5669792887 6789954237 8042954283 7426511939 4053045131...
     8629149977 2997522935 9363344270 9890870146 9426932555 5755262458...
     8327043690 0162545530 6451719711 5376165082 0595003112 5172323540...
     9314878787 6822370777 8236826223 3097377830];

B = [000 001 001 003 003 004...
     004 005 005 005 005 007...
     007 009 009 009 010 010...
     013 013 013 018 018 018...
     018 019 019 019 020 020...
     020 024 024 024 024 027...
     027 027 027 028];
```

Comment: Do you know there is a relationship?  If so, your best bet is going to be via some sort of machine learning.  [here's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning) a good place to start.

Comment: ya there is some sort of relation.

Comment: could you please suggest an application for that

Comment: downvoters? plz explain

Answer (score 1):

A brute-force method may be a good starting point. It at least give one some place to start thinking about the problem. I include the code I used to find out that for the first four numbers the following order of operations on each of the 10 digits in the gives the 3 digit code.

```
@mod, @times, @rem, @mod, @times, @plus, @rem, @rem, @mod
```

However

```
Elapsed time is 391.706191 seconds.
```

#### Code

```
data = [8955573624 000
        8727174542 001
        6144057737 001];

operations = {@plus, @minus, @times, @rdivide, @mod, @rem};

tic;
j = 1; % start from 1st row
while true
    a = data(j,1);
    digits = arrayfun(@str2mat,b(:)); b = num2str(a(1)); % Digits
    if j == 1; % Find a set of operations which converts from digits to the code
        value = NaN;
        trials = 0;
        while value ~= data(j,2) || trials > 1e3
            ops = datasample(operations,numel(digits)-1); % Random operations
            value = digits(1);
            for jj = 1:numel(digits)-1
                value = arrayfun(ops{jj},value,digits(jj+1));
            end
            trials = trials + 1;
        end
    else % Test whether it works for j > 1
        value = digits(1);
        for jj = 1:numel(digits)-1
            value = arrayfun(ops{jj},value,digits(jj+1));
        end
    end

    if value == data(j,2);
        if j == size(data,1); break; end;
        j = j + 1;
    else
        j = 1;
    end
end
toc;
```

In terms of other things to try in the framework of this code:

- Allowing for the digits to be tested as larger portions of the code. E.g. split the first code into `89,5,55,736,2,4` as opposed to only into single digits
- Allowing other/more operations
- Paralleling the attempts
- Splitting the codes into digits before the while loop (<- Probably the easiest optimization to do here)
- Trying the operations on all the codes at once (vectorising)
- Changing both code and the answer into binary and trying to find a map there

Hope that helps. Even though It does not straight up solve your problem it might help you think about it in a new way.